# ошибка подключения видео(youtube) в приложение

Tags: android

Fragment

```
public class video_1 extends Fragment implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    static private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyA3lY117wtsfzrP8Yr-mPPHv9fIKjIud7Y";
    static private final String VIDEO = "LCn0edNbA7Q";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_1, null);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) v.findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        YouTubePlayer player = null;
        player.loadVideo(VIDEO);
    }
    /*@Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }*/

}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    >

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dip" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Ошибка:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                                   at com.whitestar.klip1.video_1.onCreateView(video_1.java:28)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                                   at com.whitestar.klip1.video_1.onCreateView(video_1.java:28) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
                                                                                   at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                                   at com.whitestar.klip1.video_1.onCreateView(video_1.java:28) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Comment: ну в стэке ошибки написано "YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context."

Comment: @AdamLuisSean, помогите пожалуйста решить, по гуглил, по пробывал ничего не получается

Comment: @Aндрей, вам что вообще нужно, просто открыть видео в youtube плеере? Если так, то заюзайте просто интент  Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(context, YOUR_DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID);
 startActivity(intent);. Если не годится, то придется использовать активити унаследовавшись от YouTubeBaseActivity

Comment: @AdamLuisSean мне нужно вставить видео в фрагмент